# How to compare input data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I collected data and stored them in one table. `total`, `levelone`, `leveltwo`, `levelthree`, `rateone`, `ratetwo`, `ratethree`, and `earn` are stored in a table `"Rate"`, which is from user input.

I wrote a code to take out data from the table and do calculation in the following way:

```
if @rate.total < @rate.levelone
  @rate.earn = @rate.total * @rate.rateone
  @earn = @rate.earn
elsif @rate.levelone < @rate.total <= @rate.leveltwo
  @rate.earn = @rate.levelone * @rate.rateone
  +(@rate.total - @rate.levelone) * @rate.ratetwo
  @earn = @rate.earn
elsif @rate.leveltwo < @rate.total <= @rate.levelthree
  @rate.earn = @rate.levelone* @rate.rateone
  +(@rate.leveltwo - @rate.levelone) * @rate.ratetwo
  +(@rate.total - @rate.leveltwo) * @rate.ratethree
  @earn = @rate.earn
```

It shows:

```
undefined method `total' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't know what happened here. Is there any way to take out the data and compare?

I used form_for to make create action, after stored in the database, i took some datas out to compare, and once done, stored the result in another column, quite complicated, like this:

create_table :rates do |t|

```
t.decimal :total
t.decimal :earn
t.decimal :levelone
t.decimal :leveltwo
t.decimal :levelthree
t.decimal :rateone
t.decimal :ratetwo
t.decimal :ratethree
```

the total, levelone,two,three and rateone,two three are from user input, will stored in the database first, after that i use the data to make the above comparison and calculation, after done, the earn data will store into it as well. and show the result to user. should i do the last step by using update? thanks all

Comment: When do you want to make calculations? Before saving the record, before show in view? Can you show your model? Is the code in the controller (which action) or where?

Comment: thanks, i show it at below

Comment: For SO purpose, I suggest to merge your posted answer with your question then delete the answer. ---- About your code if I understand you should do calculation just after the form is submitted then save data and calculations results into the database? In this case you need to do it in the model, using a [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks).

Comment: This means `@rate` is `nil`. You have to assign a value to it first or wrap the whole thing in an `unless @rate.nil?` block.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, if you need to do calculation then store the data, you could do it using for example the `before_save` callback.
The code should be something like this.

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :make_calculation

  def make_calculation
    if  self.total < self.levelone
        self.earn = self.total * self.rateone
    elsif  self.levelone < self.total <= self.leveltwo
        self.earn = self.levelone * self.rateone + (self.total - self.levelone) * self.ratetwo
    elsif self.leveltwo < self.total <= self.levelthree
        self.earn = self.levelone * self.rateone + (self.leveltwo - self.levelone) * self.ratetwo + (self.total - self.leveltwo) * self.ratethree
  end

end
```

`self` is the object of the Rate class being processed for saving to database.

Answer (score 0):

Before comparing it lets check it whether `@rate` is `not nil`. in this way you can avoid the `nil` error. alternatively you can also do `if @rate.present?`

```
unless @rate.blank?
  if  @rate.total< @rate.levelone
      @rate.earn = @rate.total * @rate.rateone
      @earn = @rate.earn

  elsif  @rate.levelone < @rate.total <= @rate.leveltwo
      @rate.earn = @rate.levelone* @rate.rateone
                  +(@rate.total-@rate.levelone) *@rate.ratetwo
      @earn = @rate.earn

  elsif @rate.leveltwo < @rate.total <= @rate.levelthree
      @rate.earn = @rate.levelone* @rate.rateone
                  +(@rate.leveltwo-@rate.levelone) *@rate.ratetwo
                  +(@rate.total-@rate.leveltwo)*@rate.ratethree
      @earn = @rate.earn
end
```

Comment: Rather than just posting some code as answer, try to explain what he is doing wrong and how your proposed solution fixes it

Comment: @Subash Appreciated advice. added the explanation.

Comment: @Gabbar, thank you guys. i solve the problem, it did't show error. but it seems the "@rate.earn" could not store in the database. and the "@earn" cannot show in the view.

Comment: @JuniorChung Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you.